# How is named a certain family of probabilistic graphs with non classical information transfer

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I have a graph $G$ with $n$ inter-connected nodes. Each node can have data points in it.

[image]

The edge  transfer costs are not important. Yet what is important is the fact that there is a probability that data points will be passed from a node containing them to nodes connected to it via edges.

For example, in the given picture there is a positive probability that a point from $A$ will be transfered to any of [$B$, $C$] for example `[0.6, 0.4]`. Is there a term that describes this fact?

Comment: Isn't it (more or less) [stochastic Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_Petri_net) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: It is similar, yet $Λ$ is the array of firing rates $λ$ associated with the transitions. Thus not a node containing data decides who is next to get data but the connected to it nedes